# ValueError: could not convert string to float: 'never_thought'

Tags: python, decision-tree

I used decisionTreeClassfier in python sklearn.
And put data in the database

[screenshot of database](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Xw33L.png)

There is string data in my database.

When I fit the database,there is a wrong message.

How could I deal with it?
Thanks

Comment: I put the dataframe in screenshot of database.

Comment: I have made it. I use DictVectorizer method.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, I have dealt with it.I use *DictVectorizer* in sklearn.feature_extraction to convert my data.It is a way to hot encoder my data!